# Changes to welcome.ascx not visible outside of network

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, permissions

I updated the welcome.ascx file for a Sharepoint 2013 instance to include a link for a users to change their passwords, etc. That works great, for the most part. However, the updates I made are only visible while viewing from our internal network. When I login and view from home, it reverts back to the original links of About Me, Sign Out, and Personalize this Page, even though I removed them from the file. Does anyone have any idea how I can fix that? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Coule be two things:

1. [most probable] You updated the file (by the way: manually editing such an OOTB file is not supported) on one front-end server; you have maybe another front-end targetted by external users that does not have the modification on it.
2. Or there's a caching mechanism in your reverse-proxy: check it. Do You still have the problem when CTRL+F5 the page from the browser?

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Your reasons got me thinking... I remember the consultant saying there were 3 front end servers with some sort of proxy. My apologies for my ignorance ... I'm mainly a Front End Developer, but had this project dropped in my lap... so, I'm learning as I go. :-/ ... I will take a look at the other servers when I get to work in the morning.

Comment: That was the problem - the additional front end servers. Thank you very much for the info! Greatly appreciated!